# How to use SSMS in command prompt

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, command-prompt

I want to make a link that would run `ssms.exe` , login and open a `.sql` file.

However this: `SSMS.exe -E  -d AB2014` work fine

when this `SSMS.exe -E  -d AB2014 "C:\Users\Kazz\Desktop\AB2014\SQLQuery.sql"` opens the `.sql` 'file' but fails to login...

Comment: Could you explain your motivation for opening the file? Is it so open a file and connect to the server automatically, or to execute the SQL automatically?

Comment: no, i don't want to execute it yet, i just want to have it shown in a tab. I'm simply wonder why giving a file name suddenly stop the prog from logging.

Answer (score 2):

For my money, the tool to use when I just want to run a file (instead of have an interactive session with the server) is sqlcmd.exe. In your situation, it'd go something like:

```
sqlcmd -E -d AB2014 -i "C:\Users\Kazz\Desktop\AB2014\SQLQuery.sql" -S someServer
```

Comment: Then why do you need it to automatically log in? Either way, it looks like you're not specifying a server name; you can do so with -S.